# TouchXML unable to parse YQL result XML on a iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, touchxml

Problem 1:
Has anyone worked with TouchXML, I am facing problem parcing rssfeed that has characters like & or even &
The parser takes the url as input and doesn’t seem to parse the XML content. NSXMLParser has no such problem for the same feed URL.
Problem 2:
Another problem with NSXMLParse is when the foundCharacter() method finds “\n”
even the call like

```
if([currentElementValue isEqualToString:@"\n"])
return;

currentElementValue = [currentElementValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

both these lines doesn’t seem to eliminate the \n character.

Any help guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the newline character sequence

The XML has a "\n" in it as a string, but your line above is looking for the bytecode (0x0A I think) that is a newline character in OSX.

You need to look for "\\n" which is the character sequence *backslash-n*.

```
[currentElementValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""]
```

Will get you what you want!